# I expect this code to return undefined but it return function instead

Tags: javascript

I expect this code to print `undefined`, but it prints `function` instead. Can anyone tell me why? I am new in JS.

```
function createGreeter(greeting){
    function greet(){
        console.log(greeting,name)
    }
    return greet
}
    
let g1=createGreeter('Good Morning')
console.log(typeof g1)
let g2=createGreeter('Good Evening')
```

Comment: try `return greet()`

Comment: What do you actually want `createGreeter()` to return, and why? Also, where is `name` defined? It presumably should be a parameter to the `greet(name)` function.

Answer (score 1):

So it looks like you want to create a function that accepts a greeting but [*returns another function*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) that accepts a name (while maintaining a pointer to the variable (greeting) in its outer lexical environment when its returned) and returns the result of joining up those strings when it's called.

```js
// `createGreeter` accepts a string and
// returns a new function that accepts a name
// and when that function is called ties both strings together
function createGreeter(greeting) {
  return function (name) {
    return `${greeting}, ${name}.`;
  }
}

// Both of these return a function that accepts a name
const goodevening = createGreeter('Good evening');
const expectingyou = createGreeter('I\'ve been expecting you');

// And now we just need to call those functions with the name
console.log(goodevening('Blofeld'));
console.log(expectingyou('Mr. Bond'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning inside the function `greet` the function itself

If you want to store in a var the result of greet function then you must call it:

Instead of `return greet` you should `return greet()`

Answer (score 0):

The code says `return greet` on line 5. The value of `greet` is the function `greet` itself. You may want to change line 5 to `return greet()`, which would execute the `greet()` function and then return the return value of `greet()`, which itself is `undefined`.